# Find the index every n count in range x

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I having a simple (yet complicated) problem in my head. Excuse me for the lack of better mathematical terms but I tried explained the problem bast I can. I want to locate the indexes of N count in a range of numbers. See bellow as better explanation.

## Example

> Range $x_1 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....$

> Indexes $y_1 = 2$, $y_2 = 3$, $y_3 = 4$,

Running my formula using modulus I get a new visual range(s):

> For $y_1$ ∴ range $x_2 = 1, 2, [index_1], 3, 4, [index_2], 5, 6, [index_3], 7,8, [index_4], ... $
>
> So every second position there's a index, e.g. $1,2$ belong to $index_1$ of  $x_2$ range, and so on.

> For $y_2$ ∴ range $x_3 = `1, 2, 3, [index_1] 4, 5, 6, [index_2] 7, 8, 9, [index_3], ...$
>
> So every third position there's a index...

> For $y_3$ ∴ range $x_4 = `1, 2, 3, 4, [index_1], 5, 6, 7, 8, [index_2], ... $
>
> So every forth position there's a index...

## The Problem

> Given $z_1$ is any number in range $x_1$. How can we calculate what index $z_1$ belongs to for $x_2, x_3, x_4$ ranges.

Is there an easy formula(s) to calculate these? I trying to figure this out for programming and quite lost, any help would be great.

Comment: So, for example, in range $x_3$, $index_1$ contains $1,2,3$? Please clarify.

Comment: @user351579, Trying to find where $z_1$ belong in range(s). e.g $z_1 = 5$ for $x_3$ range the answer is $index_2$. Example 2:  $z_1 = 7$ for $x_2$ range the answer is $index_4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly what you need to find a number of index with number $m$ in $y_n$ ($x_{n+1}$) is a function $$f(n,m) = \left\lceil\frac{m}{n + 1} \right\rceil$$

Where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ is a ceiling function which returns smallest integer number which is greater or equal to the input. i.e $\lceil 1/2\rceil = 1, \lceil 1\rceil = 1, $  or formally $\lceil a \rceil = \min \{ z \in \mathbb{Z} :  z \ge a \}$.

To verify that 5 is in index 2 for $x_3$ according to $f$ we can see that $1<5/3 \le 2$ as $3 < 5 < 6$ so
$$ f(2,5) = \left\lceil\frac{5}{3} \right\rceil =2 $$

To verify that 7 is in index 4 for $x_3$ according to $f$ we can see that $3< 7/2 \le 4$ as $6 < 7 < 8$ so
$$ f(1,7) = \left\lceil\frac{7}{2} \right\rceil = 4 $$

Comment: Can you verify that this functions works e.g.:

$z_1 = 5$ for $x_3$ range the answer is $index_2$                    .            for $z_1 = 7$ for $x_2$ range the answer is $index_4$

Comment: Added examples. By the way, ceil function must be available in your programming language.

Comment: I'm happy to report that it is. The functions is quite simple now that I look at it, Want to thank you personalty for you help and you ability to understand my problem. +1.

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

To clarify Nik's answer, for every positive integer $n$, $z_1$ is in $index_m$ for range $x_n$ if and only if $m=\lceil\frac{z_1}n\rceil$. In other words, suppose $m$ is the index number, then $$m=\lceil\frac{z_1}n\rceil$$